QGIS Virtual Layer Query containing JOINS always ends up having zero results
I've got a problem JOINing together several PostGIS tables (with or without geometry) in a Virtual Layer in QGIS 3.36.3
As soon as I use a (inner) join the the layer query statement, the result set is empty. Something similar goes for left joins – right table attributes are all NULL.
Here's a concrete example (without geometry, though):
create table n(n_id varchar(38) primary key, n_txt varchar(128));
 Column |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 n_id   | character varying(38)  |           | not null | 
 n_txt  | character varying(128) |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "n_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (n_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "f" CONSTRAINT "f_f_nid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (f_nid) REFERENCES n(n_id)

insert into n values('n1', 'n1 text');
insert into n values('n2', 'n2 text');
insert into n values('n3', 'n3 text');
insert into n values('n4', 'n4 text');
create table f(f_id varchar(38) primary key, f_nid varchar(38), foreign key(f_nid) references n(n_id));
                        Table "public.f"
 Column |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 f_id   | character varying(38) |           | not null | 
 f_nid  | character varying(38) |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "f_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (f_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "f_f_nid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (f_nid) REFERENCES n(n_id)

insert into f values('f1', 'n4');
insert into f values('f2', 'n3');
insert into f values('f3', 'n2');
insert into f values('f4', 'n1');
Executing the following query in psql, returns four result rows (correctly), but using the exact same query in a virtual layer with the two above Postgres tables as "embedded layers" (both populated correctly), always returns an empty result set.
select f.f_id, n.n_id, n.n_txt from f join n on f.f_nid=n.n_id where true;
I would expect QGIS to join together the two tables just as Posgres does:
 f_id | n_id |  n_txt  
------+------+---------
 f1   | n4   | n4 text
 f2   | n3   | n3 text
 f3   | n2   | n2 text
 f4   | n1   | n1 text

and also have four rows in the virtual layer feature table.
What may be going wrong here?
Have I just found a bug or is the error on my side?
QGIS version
3.36.3-Maidenhead
QGIS code revision
2df9655469b
Qt version
5.15.8
Python version
3.11.2
GDAL/OGR version
3.6.2
PROJ version
9.1.1
EPSG Registry database version
v10.076 (2022-08-31)
GEOS version
3.11.1-CAPI-1.17.1
SQLite version
3.40.1
PostgreSQL client version
15.5 (Debian 15.5-0+deb12u1)
SpatiaLite version
5.0.1
QWT version
6.1.4
QScintilla2 version
2.13.3
OS version
Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)




Active Python plugins
spline
0.2
SelectByRelationship
0.3.3
qfieldsync
v4.9.1
mmqgis
2021.9.10
DigitizingTools
1.5.2
qgis_geonode
1.0.1
processing
2.12.99


PostgreSQL 13.9 (Debian 13.9-0+deb11u1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit


Seems rather buggy to me...but in any case, better use the DB Manager for accessing data directly from external databases - you can add the results as a (virtual) layer there, and queries are guaranteed to be executed on the DB engine.

It's possible that the where true is confusing things

@IanTurton : The 'where true' doesn't change the situation (tried it). I added it because there was a bug (#19721) that seems to have made the where-clause necessary. I added it because I wasn't sure...

@geozelot: Thank you very much for the tip. I wasn't aware that DB manager treats SQL-queries different than Virtual Layers. Seems like a very viable solution.

QGIS virtual layers are indeed SQLite virtual tables [1].
So are embedded layers. They are part of a temporary database that QGIS creates especially to build the virtual layer.
This is not exactly what a virtual layer was made to show, but you can try the following:
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name IN ('n', 'f');

The QGIS virtual layer query is not being delegated to the PostgreSQL engine, so both the syntax and the results may not be as expected.
In particular, when the primary keys are not of type INTEGER, since "Except for WITHOUT ROWID tables, all rows within SQLite tables have a 64-bit signed integer key that uniquely identifies the row within its table" [2].
A virtual table can't be a Rowid Table [3]. But, if it is also not a WITHOUT ROWID [4] table and there is not an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, the rows can't be identified. Therefore they can't be joined.
Maybe some logic should be able to be implemented in the QGIS SQLite extension defining virtual table implementation [5] to resolve the dilemma. Maybe always assume that a integer primary key does not exist and generate one automatically. Don't know.
The little thing I can think of is to wrap all the input and output tables (for the sake of safety) of the virtual layer in a chain of common table expressions that add a unique identifier attribute to the beginning of each relation:
WITH new_f AS (
 SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS new_f_id,
  *
 FROM f
), new_n AS (
 SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS new_n_id,
  *
 FROM n
), modified_source_query AS (
 select f.f_id, n.n_id, n.n_txt
 from new_f AS f
 join new_n AS n 
 on f.f_nid=n.n_id
 where true
)
SELECT
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS virtual_pk,
 *
FROM modified_source_query;

I know, it's not an elegant solution.
Any other solution that is possible would seem better to me: using BIGINT primary keys in PostgreSQL; directly create the view in PostgreSQL; or run the source query in the Database Manager and load the result set as a new layer.

[1] https://sqlite.org/vtab.html
[2] https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid
[3] https://sqlite.org/rowidtable.html
[4] https://sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html
[5] https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/providers/virtual/qgsvirtuallayersqlitemodule.cpp
